# Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true) return wrong URL

Tags: yii

I've used  Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true) in link to get root URL of server.
But It Return the URL like

**http://applicationname/applicationname/login**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the application is not deployed on root of the server

**Deployed on root of server**

Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true) return path is http://applicationname/login

**OR**

**Deployed in any folder of server**

Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true) return path is http://applicationname/applicationname/login